# Importing CSV into MySQL leaving quote at end of line

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm working with an open source data set from [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/council-tax-stock-of-properties-2015) on a Linux server running MySQL. I'm just trying to import Table CTSOP1.1, which looks like:

[image]

So my issue is when I import the file using:

```
rm -f import.log; mysql -u userxxx -p --execute="USE mydb; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Table_CTSOP1.1_2015.csv' INTO TABLE CT_2015 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;" > import.log
```

it produces some strange output:

[image]

As you can see, it leaves quotes at the end of lines and skips the next line completely, however it still seems to manage to right itself regarding the number of columns. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I was thinking that alright, just do a quick replace of the extra quotes, but there's missing lines after each line with an erroneous quote. Are you saying fix that before I import?

Comment: Are you sure the line terminators are `\n`, and not `\r\n`?  It's a shot in the dark, but I've had some odd behavior when specifying incorrect line terminators.

Comment: @lamecircle, sorry, I see now, it's skipping importing lines. Can you please verify that the quotes are standard quotes `""` and not other strange quotes? For example `˝` are actually double accent quotes.

Comment: @Sculper ARGH! why is it always so simple. Thanks a million, thats done it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @Sculper for this..

It was the very obvious use of `\r\n` rather then `\n`, case closed everyone can go home.